# Not able to change the axes position qtxlsx

Tags: c++, qt, xlsx

I have generated an Excel chart using Qtxlsx ,and i want to invert the axes from (Left/buttom) to (right/top)  but i can't find the functions to change there positions.

Here is the code

```
Chart *lineChart = xlsx.insertChart(23,3, QSize(600, 400)); 
lineChart->setChartType(Chart::CT_Line); 
lineChart->addSeries(CellRange("A4:A9"));
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Here is the  code  i've used to export the chart : 
            Chart *lineChart = xlsx.insertChart(23,3, QSize(600, 400));
            lineChart->setChartType(Chart::CT_Line);
            lineChart->addSeries(CellRange("A4:A9"));